# Selecting at least 4 questions of 12 and at least one of the first 3 questions must be taken?

Tags: combinatorics

> There are 12 questions. Students must take at least 4 questions and at least one of the first 3 questions is taken too.

How many configurations are there?

## My attempt

\begin{align}
\text{answer} &= \sum_{i=1}^3\left({3\choose i}\sum_{j=4-i}^9{9 \choose j}\right)\\
 &= 3415
\end{align}

Is it correct?

Comment: I think I am not wrong.

Comment: Correct.  another way, $\binom3 3\times(2^9-1) + \binom3 2 \times(2^9-10) + \binom3 1 \times(2^9-46)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct answer. Another way to approach it -

If there are $12$ questions, we have $2^{12}$ ways to select any number of questions including no selection $\big[{12 \choose 0} + {12 \choose 1} + ...+ {12 \choose 12}\big]$.

Out of that ${12 \choose 0} + {12 \choose 1} + {12 \choose 2} + {12 \choose 3} = 299$ are selections with less than $4$ questions.

Similarly if we do not select any of the first $3$ questions, there are $2^9$ ways to select questions and out of that ${9 \choose 0} + {9 \choose 1} + {9 \choose 2} + {9 \choose 3} = 130$ are selections with less than $4$ questions.

So the solution we are interested in $ = 2^{12} - 299 - (2^9 - 130) = 3415$.